# foreach loop multidimensional array but only loop through array elements with specific key

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

I am creating following array that contains all products and all their categories:

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT product_nr, category FROM erp_product_categories",ARRAY_A);
$product_categories = array();
  foreach($result as $row){
    $product_categories[$row["product_nr"]][] = $row["category"];
  }
```

(product_nr is an integer and category is a string)

Then i want to check if one of the categories of a product matches with an other variable and return true if thats the case:

```
foreach($product_categories[$ean] as $product_categorie) {
    $manages_post = in_array( $product_categorie, $this->term_link_conditions );

    if($manages_post == true){
        break;
    }
}
return $manages_post;
```

But I am getting the error

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

is it not possible to loop only through elements of an array with a specific key?

Edit:
The array looks like this

```
Array
(
    [10001] => Array       //product_nr
    (
        [0] => 1           //category
        [1] => 4           //category
    )

    [10002] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 20
    )
    //...
)
```

Comment: what is the value of `$product_categories` and `$ean`?

Comment: It means the array is empty or does not exist.

Comment: `$product_categorie` is actually an array of categories? Your naming is so confusing. Also it doesn't contain safety nets. For instance if a product doesn't have a category, it doesn't appear in the array, even though I'd expect the product id to be there, but the content being an empty array for the categories. Last but not least, have you considered querying just the categories for the `$ean` instead of getting all and then filtering them in PHP code?

Comment: what is $ean in  foreach($product_categories[$ean] as $product_categorie) {

Comment: @Shibon $ean is the same as 'product_nr'

Comment: can u dump the arayy value by key like this var_dump($product_categories[10001]);

Comment: @Shibon yes, i can dump it. it gives me the categories for the product like it should

Comment: Check the indexes are they integers or strings, that might lead to odd mismatches.

Comment: I thinking ur issue is here foreach($product_categories[$ean] as $product_categorie) {}
Try to save it in varaable like $variable =$product_categories[10001] in a variable an do in_array($variable,1);

Answer (score 0):

You should check that what you are passing to foreach is an array by using the `is_array` function

If you are not sure it's going to be an array you can always check using the following PHP example code:

```html
if (is_array($product_categories[$ean])) {

  foreach ($product_categories[$ean] as $product_categorie) {
   //do something
  }
}
```

Check out all your foreach statements, and look if the thing before the as, to make sure it is actually an array. Use`var_dump` to dump it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
if(is_array($product_categories) && sizeof($product_categories) > 0) {
    foreach($product_categories as $key => $product_categorie) {
        if($manages_post = in_array($key, $this->term_link_conditions)){
            return $manages_post;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to check the key in in_array, i want to check values with a specific key (product_nr (=ean) ) For example if the key is 10002, then i want that the following values are checked:                                     [10002] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1    [1] => 2     [2] => 8      //check categories 1, 2 and 8
        )

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do this

```
$product_category = $product_categories[$ean];

            if (is_array($product_category)) {
                $matches = array_intersect($product_category, $this->term_link_conditions);
                if(sizeof($matches) > 0){
                    $manages_post = true;
                }
            }
```